# How to install luaver in Windows?

Tags: windows, lua, mingw

Im sorry to bother you with something that might seem so basic, but Im just starting out and after installing lua on my pc, I found out that I needed version 5.1 instead of 5.3, so searching for how to keep both of them I found luaver, https://github.com/DhavalKapil/luaver. But I have had no luck installing it on windows, I tried using curl but to be honest I have no idea how to use it so I just copied the code on luaver but it didnt work (most likely because that was a code for Unix).

So if any of you kind experts could help me with this or at least direct me to some other alternative to have and change between two versions of lua it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems luaver doesn't support Windows directly.  Are you using cygwin or mingw?

Comment: I just started learning that, Im using mingw through Msys.